# Using Spring's KeyHolder with programmatically-generated primary keys

Tags: spring, oracle10g, primary-key, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to perform an insert into a table.  The table uses a NEXTVAL on a sequence to obtain the primary key.  I then want this generated ID to be passed back to me.  I am using Spring's KeyHolder implementation like this:

```
KeyHolder key = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(Constants.INSERT_ORDER_STATEMENT, params, key);
```

However, when I run this statement, I am getting:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: The generated key is not of a supported numeric type. Unable to cast [oracle.sql.ROWID] to [java.lang.Number]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder.getKey(GeneratedKeyHolder.java:73)
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong method on `JdbcTemplate`. The only one of the `update` methods that would seem to match your code fragment is

```
int update(String sql, Object... args)
```

If so, you're passing `params` and `key` as a two-element vargs array, and `JdbcTemplate` is treating `key` as a normal bind parameters, and mis-interpreting it.

The only public `update` method on `JdbcTemplate` that takes a `KeyHolder` is

```
int update(PreparedStatementCreator psc, KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder)
```

So you'll need to rephrase your code to use that.

Comment: misleading, check below answer of Konstantin

Answer (score 23):

Just solved a similar issue - with Oracle you need to use another method (from `NamedParameterJdbcOperations`)  -

```
int update(String sql,
           SqlParameterSource paramSource,
           KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder,
           String[] keyColumnNames)
           throws DataAccessException
```

with keyColumnNames containing auto-generated columns, in my case just ["Id"]. Otherwise all you get is ROWID. See [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder-) for details.

Comment: Thanks this answer the question better than previous answers and also solve my problem

Answer (score 5):

You have to execute the `JdbcTemplate.update(PreparedStatementCreator p, KeyHolder k)`.

The key returned from the database will be injected into the `KeyHolder` parameter object.

An example:

```
final String INSERT_ORDER_STATEMENT 
       = "insert into order (product_id, quantity) values(?, ?)";

KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(
            Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
                    INSERT_ORDER_STATEMENT, new String[] { "id" });
                ps.setInt(1, order.getProductId());
                ps.setInt(2, order.getQuantity());
                return ps;
            }
        }, keyHolder);
```

More information can be found [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys) in the reference documentation.

Comment: This is actually returning ROWID in holder and not a Number!

Answer (score 5):

No elaborate on @konstantin answer: Here is a fully working example:
Assuming Database is Oracle and column name which store generated Id is "GENERATED_ID" ( Can be any name).
NOTE: I used NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(....) In this example NOT JdbcTemplate class of Spring.

```
       public Integer insertRecordReturnGeneratedId(final MyObject obj)
            {
            final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE  VALUES(GENERATED_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :param1, :param2)";
            try
                {
                    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue( "param1", obj.getField1() ).addValue( "param2",  obj.getField1() ) ;
                    final KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
                    this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update( INSERT_QUERY, parameters, holder, new String[] {"GENERATED_ID" } );
                    Number generatedId = holder.getKey();
                   // Note: USING holder.getKey("GENERATED_ID") IS ok TOO.
                    return generatedId.intValue();
                }
                catch( DataAccessException dataAccessException )
                {
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `vets` (
  `id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `last_name` (`last_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


public @Data class Vet {
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
}

@Repository
public class VetDaoImpl implements VetDao {
/** Logger. */
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VetDaoImpl.class);

private static final String INSERT_VET = "INSERT INTO vets (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name)";

@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

@Override
public Number insertVet(final Vet vet) {
    MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramSource.addValue("first_name", vet.getFirstname());
    paramSource.addValue("last_name", vet.getLastname());
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    int nbRecord = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_VET, paramSource, keyHolder, new String[] {"id" });
    LOGGER.info("insertVet: id ["+keyHolder.getKey()+"]");
    return nbRecord;
}
}
```